# Programmatically access one website from multiple locations?

Tags: python, vpn, tor

I have a hypothesis that you could increase your chances of getting tickets for sell-out events by attempting to access the website from multiple locations. Just to be clear i'm not trying to be that guy who buys ALL of the tickets for events and then sells them on at 10X the price, incidentally i'm talking specifically about one event, Glastonbury festival, for which I have tried many years to buy a ticket, and never been successful.

The problem is that you literally can't get on the site when the tickets get released.

So i guess there area few qualifying questions to work out if i need to even ask the main question.

- What is actually happening on the website's server(s) at these times? Does the sheer volume of traffic cause some users to get 'rejected'?
- Is it down to chance who gets through to the site?
- Would trying to access the site multiple times increase your chances?
- If so, would you have to try to access it from multiple locations? I.e. as opposed to just opening multiple tabs in the same browser.

Which brings me to the actual question:

- Could this be achieved as simply as using Python to open multiple instances of Tor?

Comment: If anything, Tor will actually reduce your chances to successfully access a website which is already under heavy traffic (Tor bounces your packets all over the place).

Comment: https://theringer.com/ticket-industry-problem-solution-e4b3b71fdff6#.w3pckilly

Comment: That article was very interesting but a lot of it becomes irrelevant when talking about something like Glastonbury. For Glasto you can only buy 8 tickets, you can't resell tickets because you have to register first and your ticket has a picture of your face on it. The problem is there are 1,000,000 people trying to get on a website at once to buy 180,000 ticekts, you get request timeout after request timeout until eventually you get through to a page which says 'SOLD OUT;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has very little to do with *your* connection. The server is simply drowning in requests. More requests from different locations won't help you. A faster connection might help you get into the queue before anyone else, but multiple connections won't help. If you really want tickets, figure out how to move through the website in an automated way such that you submit a request to move through the menus faster than any human could.